# Make a page with an overview of all available api's in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm making web API's whit ASP.NET MVC. I've get an example form a theater and I see that he has made an overview of all available API's. How Can I made that into my own website?

Here is the overview:

[image]

This is the detail page where you can see the result in Json and XML.

[image][image]

How can I make this?

Comment: When you create a `web-api` project, you get this included in the Areas->Help Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, if you create a new `web-api` project then they will be there already under your project -> Areas -> HelpPage.

If however you do not have them (you may have started the project already etc), then you can use the following commands in the package manager console:

For a C# application: 
`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage`

For a Visual Basic application: 
`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage.VB`

See here for more detail: [Create Help Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages)